# How to develop a function that accepts a vectors of character which corresponds to the column component of a dataframe?

Tags: r, string, function

This is my current dataset called details.

```
> details$names<- c("James Johnson","Michael Jones","Robert Miller","Christopher Smith","Richard Nolan","Constantine Wilson","Mountabatteen Keizman")
```

I want to extract the part of names considering these 2 aspects:

1) Starting from the left, extract all characters until a space or a hypen (or minus sign) is reached.

2) Extract no more than ten characters.

I tried to do this by using this code:

```
> abrevStrings<- function(details$names) 
{   
gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])","([a-z])([A-Z])<= 10",details$names) 
}
```

But I didn't get the output I wanted.

My desired output can be seen below:

```
James 
Michael 
Robert 
Christophe 
Richard 
Constantin 
Mountabatt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would using `sub` and `substr` by removing everything after whitespace or hyphen and then select only first 10 characters.

```
abrevStrings <- function(x) {
   substr(sub("\\s+.*|-.*", "", x), 1, 10)
}

abrevStrings(details$names)
#[1] "James"      "Michael"    "Robert"     "Christophe" "Richard" 
#    "Constantin" "Mountabatt"
```

---

Or another option is to split the strings on whitespace or hyphen and take the substring of the first part of the string.

```
sapply(strsplit(details$names, "\\s+|-"), function(x) substr(x[1], 1, 10))
```

**data**

```
details <- data.frame(names = c("James Johnson","Michael Jones","Robert Miller",
           "Christopher Smith","Richard Nolan","Constantine Wilson",
           "Mountabatteen Keizman"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you so much. And can you tell me how can we use return function within the function? For eg:                                                                  abrevStrings <- function(x)                                                                                      
 {
   substr(sub("\\s+.*|-.*", "", x), 1, 10); return(vec)                                                                                                                                                              
}

Comment: @Alex you don't need an explicit `return` statement as the function returns whatever is the last statement in the function. However, if you still need it you can do `abrevStrings <- function(x) {
  vec <- substr(sub("\\s+.*|-.*", "", x), 1, 10);
  return(vec)
}`